# Flutter: re-render child widget on parent state change

Tags: flutter, dart

So a have a stateful parent with a `timer` value. This timer can be reset by the user. I also have a child stateful widget with an animation controller. The parent passes the `timer` value to this child to reset the animation. Here is some code:

```dart
class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  int timer = 20;
  
  void _userInput() {
    setState(() {
      timer = 20;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Child(
      time: timer
    );
  }
}
```

**Note**: this is striped down for simplicity

So when my user triggers the `_userInput` method, the timer value gets changed but the child doesn't. Here is my full child widget:

```dart
class TimerProgress extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerProgress({
    Key key,
    @required this.time,
    @required this.onCompleted
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int time;
  final Function onCompleted;

  @override
  _TimerProgressState createState() => _TimerProgressState();
}

class _TimerProgressState extends State<TimerProgress> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _widthAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(seconds: widget.time),
      vsync: this
    );

    _widthAnimation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 200,
      end: 0
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.linear
    ));

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.value == 1) {
        widget.onCompleted();
      }
    });

    _controller.forward();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

So this all works, but ideally I want the animation to be reset, which doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initState` runs only once per state instance.

Implement resetting the time inside `didUpdateWidget`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawScrollbarState/didUpdateWidget.html

You can't (cause it will cause recursive loop, `setState` will trigger `didUpdateWidget` again) and shouldn't (after this method is invoked, `build` is being called) have to call `setState` inside this method.

Runnable example: https://www.dartpad.dev/848976603f866f4e3aa6030aba8addf7?null_safety=true

[image]

Comment: I tried implementing this. Didn't work. Am I doing this incorrectly?

`
AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _widthAnimation;
  int duration; //new

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(seconds: duration),
      vsync: this
    );

    // same as before

    super.initState();
  }

  void didUpdateWidget(old) {
    duration = widget.time;

    super.didUpdateWidget(old);
  }
`

Comment: I've added an example on dartpad, please have a look.

Comment: Still can't get it to work... I made a dartpad: https://www.dartpad.dev/4e05042e7954e29d7a79110b67617f89?null_safety=true. I want to reset the timer when the parent state changes

Comment: https://www.dartpad.dev/8a3390f3e4a0770546c69e20081ac624?null_safety=true